# PE Section Data

Tags: c, winapi

I have an Portable Executable ( .exe ) file and I want to retrieve its sections. I did like this:

```
IMAGE_DOS_HEADER* pDOSHeader = (IMAGE_DOS_HEADER*) buffer; // DOS Header
IMAGE_NT_HEADERS* pNTHeaders = (IMAGE_NT_HEADERS*) ((BYTE *) pDOSHeader + pDOSHeader->e_lfanew); // PE Header
```

Everything good until now. I found this:

> The section table: This follows immediately after the PE header. It is an array of IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER structures, each containing the information about one section in the PE file such as its attribute and virtual offset. Remember the number of sections is the second member of FileHeader (6 bytes from the start of the PE header). If there are 8 sections in the PE file, there will be 8 duplicates of this structure in the table. Each header structure is 40 bytes apiece and there is no "padding" between them.

Now, when I do like this:

`IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER* pSection = (IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER*) 
(pNTHeaders->FileHeader.PointerToSymbolTable);`

or:

```
IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER* pSection = (IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER*) ((BYTE *) pNTHeaders + sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS));
```

pSection's address is NULL ( 0 ).

I have to mention that **buffer** variable is where I read the PE's data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need do use the `SizeOfOptionalHeader` value to skip the optional header. Do not rely on it being of fixed size. `winnt.h` has a macro that you should use:

```
#define IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION( ntheader ) ((PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)  \
    ((ULONG_PTR)(ntheader) +                                      \
     FIELD_OFFSET( IMAGE_NT_HEADERS, OptionalHeader ) +           \
     ((ntheader))->FileHeader.SizeOfOptionalHeader   \
    ))
```